# OrientDB 2.2.3 in OSGI environment

Tags: osgi, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have a pretty small OSGI application running in Apache Karaf, and it work fine on OrientDB version 2.1.11. But I've faced with following error when tried to start it on new 2.2.3 version:

```
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error on opening database 'remote:/localhost/testdb'
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:187)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool$DatabaseDocumentTxPolled.<init>(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:118)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool$DatabaseDocumentTxPolled.<init>(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:114)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.initQueue(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:442)
```

This error occures on application install time when it's trying to initialise DB connection pool. After some debugging I found that the root problem is in method  registerEngines() of class com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient where OrientDB classloader tries to find all implmentations of OEngine interface:

```
    Iterator<OEngine> engines = OClassLoaderHelper.lookupProviderWithOrientClassLoader(OEngine.class, classLoader);
```

This call returns only 2 implementations, plocal and memory (located in the same bundle as registerEngines() - orientdb-core). The remote engine (com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OEngineRemote) is located in orientdb-client bundle and OrientDB classloader can't find it.

Here is code fragment that creates DB connection poll and produces described error:

```
    log.info("Creating OrientDB connection pool");
    OGlobalConfiguration.NETWORK_BINARY_DNS_LOADBALANCING_ENABLED.setValue(true);
    OPartitionedDatabasePool connectionPool = new OPartitionedDatabasePool(url, user, password);
    log.info(String.format("Created OrientDB connection pool: url=%s", url));
```

Comment: Hi @Tim, can you post the code used to connect to the db? Thx in advance

Comment: Hello, @Michela Bonizzi, I've added code to original message

Comment: Hi @Tim we are facing similar issues reported here: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6306